# Возможность замены Android своим приложением

Tags: android, android-sdk

очень интересует данный вопрос, есть ли на сегодняшний день возможность установки своего приложения на Android так, чтобы телефон или планшет работал только с ним, то есть при включении сразу бы запускалось мое приложение и возможности выхода из него не было. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, конечно, слишком общий. Если отвечать ровно на то, о чем вы спросили - да, можно. Называют эту "корневую" программу launcher, их можно поставить из гуглплея на любой вкус и цвет или сделать самому, при должном терпении. [Пример](http://learn-android.ru/news/sozdaem_prostoj_launcher_na_android/2015-02-14-49.html)

Comment: Добрый день, если конкретнее, можно ли снести систему андроида так, чтобы поставить туда свое приложение, то есть я хочу полностью избавится от ПО андроида и поставить свое ПО

Comment: Прям полностью избавиться от андроида вы не сможете. Точнее не так, вы можете под какой-то конкретный девайс собрать собственный кастомный билд, вырезав оттуда все лишнее и подправиви не лишнее. Но трудозатраты будут фантастические. Если у вас цель именно показывать свое приложение вместо "рабочего стола", то это не сложно, простейший лаунчер пишется за пару часов гугления. Но при этом останутся старые приложения с настройками, шторка  со статусбаром и т.д и тп.

Comment: вот мне как раз таки и нужно избавится от того, что Вы описали. А вариант кастомного билда, Вы имеете в виду вырезать напрямую, или же взять какой то готовый эмулятор и запилить его под себя ?

Comment: Эмулятором жив не будешь. Вам нужно взять кастомный билд андроид под ваше устройство с октрытым кодом, если такие бывают, прокачаться в понимании этой системы до полубожественного уровня и вырезать ненужное так, чтоб ничего не сломалось. Универсального решения вы не получите, т.к. на разных устройствах разное железо и даже архитектуры. Придется проделывать работу под каждое устройство отдельно